# Convert Java object of scala.collection.Seq<String> to python list

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

In a pyspark `sparkSession`, with `sc` as my `sparkContext`, calling the `getRDDStorageInfo()` Java sparkContext, `_jsc.sc()`, method returns a JavaObject instance of `RDDInfo[]` that I can iterate over in python.

`sc._jsc.sc().getRDDStorageInfo()`  returns `JavaObject id=o473`

So the following works:

```
for s in sc._jsc.sc().getRDDStorageInfo():
    print s.name()
    print s.memSize()
    print s.numPartitions()
    print s.numCachedPartitions()
```

However, the Java sparkContext method `listFiles()` returns a JavaObject of `scala.collection.Seq<String>`.

`sc._jsc.sc().listFiles()`  returns `JavaObject id=o475`

and when I try and iterate over that I get `TypeError: 'JavaObject' object is not iterable`

How can I convert the JavaObject of `scala.collection.Seq<String>` into a python list (or other python iterable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call scala methods `size` and `apply` to do this

```
files = sc._jsc.sc().listFiles()
py_files = [files.apply(i) for i in range(files.size())]
```